# Cropping Image whatever is the file extension

Tags: jquery

HTML markup:

```
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://1stimg.jpg?width=300"></a>
</div>
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://2ndimg.jpeg?width=300"></a>
</div>
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://3rdimg.png?width=300"></a>
</div>
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://4thimg.gif?width=300"></a>
</div>
```

I am using the following code below to crop the image above but it works only for the 1st image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.postbody img").each(function() {
    var iu = this.src;
    iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('jpg')) + 'jpg?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
    this.src = iu;
});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `indexOf('.')` instead of `indexOf('jpg')` for whatever it is worth.
And why do you want to fix it to 'jpg' only?
Why don't you request for a smaller image already?

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing all the source attributes, no matter if it matches the extension or not.

Check for the proper extension before you do the replace :

```
$(function() {
    $("div.postbody img").each(function() {
        var iu = this.src;
        if (iu.indexOf('jpg')!=-1) {
            iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('jpg')) + 'jpg?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
            this.src = iu;
        }
        else if (iu.indexOf('jpeg')!=-1) {
            iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('jpeg')) + 'jpeg?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
            this.src = iu;
        }
    });
});
```